# In Openframeworks(C++) cannot initialize OfImage Object in Thread class due to texture allocation error

Tags: c++, multithreading, openframeworks

I am trying to use the OfThread Class in OpenFrameworks. The purpose of this thread is to generate fractal images that changes color according to the FFT results every fixed amount of time.

However, When I was trying to allocate memory space for the OfImage object, it throws an runtime error:
    `EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x0)`

Also, I tried to do this in the main thread, it works perfectly. So I wonder if the thread class has anything to do with the inability to allocate space for this OfImage Object.

Source Code:

```
//in MyThread.h
class MyThread: public ofThread
{
public:
    ofImage img;
}

//in MyThread.cpp
void MyThread::threadedFunction()
{
    img.allocate(1024, 768, OF_IMAGE_COLOR); //error appears here

    while(isThreadRunning())
    {
        fftVals = ofSoundGetSpectrum(fftSize);
        resetColormap();
        fractal();
    }
}
```

[Here is the screen shot of the runtime stack:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYCCJ.png)

Answer (score 2):

`ofImage` wraps both an `ofPixels` object and an `ofTexture` object.  `ofPixels` represents the pixels in RAM and `ofTexture` represents the pixels as a texture on the GPU.  **By default, when pixels are loaded into `ofImage`, the pixels are saved into the internal `ofPixels` object *and* they are automatically uploaded to the GPU via the `ofTexture`**.

**OpenGL-related functions (like uploading the pixels to the GPU via `ofTexture`) only work in the main thread**.  Thus when you attempt to modify or set the pixels in `ofImage` in a non-primary thread, the automatic process of uploading the pixels to the GPU fails.

Typically this is solved by either using `ofPixels` alone in external threads or if using `ofImage`, tell the `ofImage` not to automatically upload the texture to the GPU like this:

```
ofImage image;
image.setUseTexture(false);
image.load(...); // This will not automatically upload to the GPU.
```

Then, from the main thread, the pixels can be sent to the graphics card with a call to:

```
image.update();
```

In cases like this, I often only store images as `ofPixels` in the threaded classes, then when the threads are joined, I call `ofImage`'s `::setFromPixels(...)` function to get a drawable `ofImage` image.

Example (a multi-threaded IP video grabber that uses `ofPixels` to capture raw data and then transfers that to an `ofImage` for drawing):

https://github.com/bakercp/ofxIpVideoGrabber/blob/master/src/IPVideoGrabber.h#L202

Further reference on `ofImage` texture behavior:
http://openframeworks.cc/documentation/graphics/ofImage/#show_setUseTexture